# Show elements between rows in a table

Tags: r, shiny, golem

I have a df dataframe. I would like to display each row.
I would like to add on each line a button *Show_Hide* which will display other ui element below line l (between lines l and l+1).

<s>How can I do this ? I was thinking of created a conditionalPanel but how can I test if the button is clicked?</s>

I created a lapply loop to listen to all *Show_Hide* buttons but i get an error

```
mod_test_ui <- function(id){ ns <- NS(id) tagList( 
   uiOutput(ns("table")))}


mod_test_server <- function(id){ moduleServer( id, function(input, output, session){ ns <- session$ns

    df <- reactiveVal(data.frame(index = 1:5, nom = c("Alice", "Bob", "Charlie", "David", "Eve"), val1 = c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50), val2 = c(5, 4, 3, 2, 1)))

    df2 <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(20 * 10), nrow = 20))

    output$table <- renderUI({
      lapply(1:nrow(df()), function(i) {
        id_sh <- paste0("sh", df()$index[i])
        condition_sh <- sprintf("input.%s %% 2 === 0", id_sh)
        id_del <- paste0("del", df()$index[i])
        id_table <- paste0("t", df()$index[i])
        id_name <- paste0("name", df()$index[i])
        fluidRow(
          column(2, p(df()$index[i])),
          column(2, textInput(ns(id_name), label = NULL, value = df()$nom[i])),
          column(2, p(df()$val1[i])),
          column(2, p(df()$val2[i])),
          column(2, actionButton(ns(id_sh), label = "Show_Hide")),
          column(2, actionButton(ns(id_del), label = "Delete")),
          column(
            12,
              dataTableOutput(ns(id_table)),
          ),
        )})})

    #Observe button "Show_Hide"
      lapply(1:nrow(df()), function(i) {
        observeEvent(input[[paste0("sh", df()$index[i])]], {
          cat("Button Show_Hide pressed : ", paste0("sh", df()$index[i]), "\n")
          id_table <- paste("t", i)
          output[[id_table]] <- renderTable(head(df2))
        })})
})}
```

When I run the application golem::run_dev() I get an error:

Warning: Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext: Operation not allowed without an active reactive context.
• You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive consumer.

---

```
mod_test_ui <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    uiOutput(ns("table"))
  )
}

mod_test_server <- function(id){
  moduleServer( id, function(input, output, session){
    ns <- session$ns

    df <- reactiveVal(data.frame(
      index = 1:5,
      nom = c("Alice", "Bob", "Charlie", "David", "Eve"),
      val1 = c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50),
      val2 = c(5, 4, 3, 2, 1)
    ))

    df2 <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(20 * 10), nrow = 20))

    output$table <- renderUI({
      if(nrow(df()!= 0)){
        lapply(1:nrow(df()), function(i) {
          id_sh <- paste0("sh", df()$index[i])
          condition_sh <- sprintf("input.%s %% 2 === 0", id_sh)
          id_del <- paste0("del", df()$index[i])
          id_table <- paste0("t", df()$index[i])
          id_name <- paste0("name", df()$index[i])
          fluidRow(
            column(2, p(df()$index[i])),
            column(2, textInput(ns(id_name), label = NULL, value = df()$nom[i])),
            column(2, p(df()$val1[i])),
            column(2, p(df()$val2[i])),
            column(2, actionButton(ns(id_sh), label = "Show_Hide")),
            column(2, actionButton(ns(id_del), label = "Delete")),
            column(
              12,
              uiOutput(ns(id_table)),
            ),
          )
        })
      }
    })


    lapply(1:5, function(i) {
      observeEvent(input[[paste0("del", i)]], {
        df(subset(df(), index != i))
      })
    })

    lapply(1:5, function(i) {
      observeEvent(input[[paste0("sh", i)]], {
        id_t <- paste0("t", i)
        if(input[[paste0("sh", i)]]%%2 == 0){
          output[[id_t]] <- renderTable(NULL)
        } else {
          output[[id_t]] <- renderTable(head(df2))
        }
        cat("Bouton cliqué:", id_t, "\n")

      })
    })

  })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I misunderstood where you want to place the conditional panel but here is the idea.

An action button initially takes the value `0`, and this value is incremented by `1` each time you click the button. So, if you want to detect the click in a conditional panel, you can check whether the value is odd or even, i.e. whether it equals 0 modulo 2:

```
input.theButtonId % 2 === 0
```

Thus:

```r
library(shiny)

mod_test_ui <- function(id){ 
  ns <- NS(id) 
  tagList( 
    uiOutput(ns("table"))
  )
}

mod_test_server <- function(id){
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session){ 
    ns <- session$ns
    
    df <- reactiveVal(data.frame(
      index = 1:5, 
      nom = c("Alice", "Bob", "Charlie", "David", "Eve"), 
      val1 = c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50), 
      val2 = c(5, 4, 3, 2, 1)
    ))
    
    output$table <- renderUI({
      lapply(1:nrow(df()), function(i) {
        id_sh <- paste0("sh", df()$index[i])
        condition_sh <- sprintf("input.%s %% 2 === 0", id_sh)
        id_del <- paste0("del", df()$index[i])
        fluidRow(
          column(2, p(df()$index[i])),
          column(
            2, 
            conditionalPanel(
              condition = condition_sh,
              textInput(
                ns(paste0("nom_", df()$index[i])), 
                label = NULL, value = df()$nom[i]
              ),
              ns = ns
            )
          ),
          column(2, p(df()$val1[i])),
          column(2, p(df()$val2[i])),
          column(2, actionButton(ns(id_sh), label = "Show_Hide")),
          column(2, actionButton(ns(id_del), label = "Delete"))
        )
      })
    })
    
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  mod_test_ui("x")
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  mod_test_server("x")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Hello @StéphaneLaurent, thank for your help. My post wasn't very clear because I didn't know where I wanted to go myself. Your code allowed me to better understand what I wanted. The conditionPanel not matching what I want to do. I edited my post. I added a line to display other ui elements, for example a table (df2) and when you click on *Show_Hide* it displays the df2 table. The problem is that I have to listen to all "Show_hide" buttons and then retrieve the id to add the table to the right place.

Comment: @dia05 You get this error because the reactive value `df` in `lapply(1:nrow(df()),` is outside a reactive context. I don't understand why you don't want to put the table inside a conditional panel?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurant I thought it was a good idea but actually not at all. I removed the conditionalPanel.  df2 is a exemple but in reality i read a csv file and I assign it to df2. For each line df2 is different. I edited my post and put the code I wanted. Thank for your help.

Comment: @dia05 So, is your problem solved now? Remark: you should not put an output slot inside an observer, as you do at the end of your code. Instead you can do `tableOutput(ns("t1"))` and `output$t1 <- renderTable(Tables$tbl1)` where `Tables` is initially `reactiveValues(tbl1 = NULL, ..., tbl5 = NULL)` and in the observer you change `Tables$tbl1`, ..., `Tables$tbl5`. Am I clear?